# How to bind JSON data in a table using jQuery DataTables

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, datatables

I want to bind data to a table using jQuery DataTables.

I am returning the data using action result and converting it to JSON in view, data is not displaying in the table,  only blank columns are shown.

***Here is the view part***

```
  @model Guardian.Core.Model.Models.PatientMedicationsCollection
    @{
        var ModelJsonData = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model);
        Layout = null;
    }

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var MedicationMasterData = JSON.parse(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ModelJsonData)));
        var CCDAChecked;
        var LatestCCDA;
        var AllCCDA;
        var CLaimsChecked;
        var AllClaims;
        var Last6Month;
        var OneYear;
        var FilteredData = [];

        $(document).ready(function () {
            debugger;

            $.each(MedicationMasterData, function (idx, obj) {
                FilteredData.push(this);

            });
            FilterTable(MedicationMasterData);
});
        function FilterTable(FilteredData) {
            debugger;
            FData = JSON.stringify(FilteredData)
            $('#PatientMedications').DataTable({
                "scrollX": 100,
                "paging": true,
                "pagingType": "full_numbers",
                "dom": '<"toolbar">frtip',
                "aaData": FData,

                columns: [
                    { title: "PatientID" },
                    { title: "FirstName" },
                    { title: "LastName" },
                    { title: "DOB." },
                    { title: "Gender" },
                    { title: "Source" },
                    { title: "SourceCreatedDate" },
                    { title: "SourceKeyID" },
                    { title: "LatestCCDA" },
                    { title: "Code" },
                    { title: "CodeType" },
                    { title: "DrugName" },
                    { title: "DrugDecriptionsM" },
                    { title: "StartDate" },
                    { title: "StopDate" },
                    { title: "Instructions" },
                    { title: "Status" },
                    { title: "DoseQuantity" },
                    { title: "RateQuantity" },
                    { title: "RateQuantityUnit" },
                    { title: "DrugDecriptionsM" },
                    { title: "ClaimLineFromDate" },
                    { title: "DaysSupply" },
                    { title: "DOSAGEFORMNAME" },
                    { title: "ROUTENAME" },
                    { title: "ST" }

                ]

            });
```

**Controler Part where we are returning the data using action result**

```
public ActionResult PatientMedications(int patientID)
            {
                return PartialView(patientrepository.PatientMedications(patientID));
            }
```

Comment: A couple of questions - Why are you returning a 'PartialView'? Why don't you return a json object instead of doing all that client-side processing Use `return Json(new { aaData=`

Comment: I did not catch your question clearly but i guess your column name should match. Then it will show the data

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#PatientMedications').dataTable({
  "aaData": data,   //this is your JSON object, which is what is showing in your post above with console.log(data)
  "aoColumns": [{
    "mDataProp": "PatientID"
  }, {
    "mDataProp": "FirstName"
  }]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

- Use [`columns.data`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data) option instead of [`columns.title`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.title) to define data source for the column from the row's data object.
- Do not pass JSON string to `aaData`, array is expected instead. Remove line with `JSON.stringify()`.
- Use [`data`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/data) option name instead of retired `aaData`. I assume that `FilteredData` is an array of objects.

```js
$('#PatientMedications').DataTable({
    "scrollX": 100,
    "pagingType": "full_numbers",
    "dom": '<"toolbar">frtip',
    "data": FilteredData,
    "columns": [
        { data: "PatientID" },
        { data: "FirstName" },
        { data: "LastName" },
        { data: "DOB." },
        { data: "Gender" },
        { data: "Source" },
        { data: "SourceCreatedDate" },
        { data: "SourceKeyID" },
        { data: "LatestCCDA" },
        { data: "Code" },
        { data: "CodeType" },
        { data: "DrugName" },
        { data: "DrugDecriptionsM" },
        { data: "StartDate" },
        { data: "StopDate" },
        { data: "Instructions" },
        { data: "Status" },
        { data: "DoseQuantity" },
        { data: "RateQuantity" },
        { data: "RateQuantityUnit" },
        { data: "DrugDecriptionsM" },
        { data: "ClaimLineFromDate" },
        { data: "DaysSupply" },
        { data: "DOSAGEFORMNAME" },
        { data: "ROUTENAME" },
        { data: "ST" }
    ]
});
```

Comment: Yes it array of object but if we use data it will not work so I used aaData and mData and its working fine

Comment: @AdeshGaonkar, what DataTables version are you using?

Comment: We are using DataTables of version  1.10.4

Answer (score 0):

**I used  aaData and mData and its working fine**

```
 function FilterTable(FilteredData) {

        $('#PatientMedications').DataTable({
            "bDestroy": true,
            "bRetrieve": true,
            "scrollX": 100,
            "paging": true,
            "pagingType": "full_numbers",
            "dom": '<"toolbar">frtip',
            "aaData": FilteredData,

            "aoColumns": [
                { "mData": "PatientID" },
                { "mData": "FirstName" },
                { "mData": "LastName" },
                { "mData": "DateOfBirth" },
                { "mData": "Gender" },
                { "mData": "Source" },
                { "mData": "SourceCreatedDate" },
                { "mData": "SourceKeyID" },
                { "mData": "LatestCCDA" },
                { "mData": "Code" },
                { "mData": "CodeType" },
                { "mData": "DrugName" },
                { "mData": "Drug Descriptions" },
                { "mData": "StartDate" },
                { "mData": "StopDate" },
                { "mData": "Instructions" },
                { "mData": "Status" },
                { "mData": "DoseQuantity" },
                { "mData": "RateQuantity" },
                { "mData": "RateQuantityUnit" },
                { "mData": "ClaimLineFromDate" },
                { "mData": "QuantityDispensed" },
                { "mData": "DaysSupply" },
                { "mData": "DosageFormName" },
                { "mData": "ROUTENAME" },
                { "mData": "ST" }

            ]

        });
```